# Maven install doesn't work

Tags: eclipse, maven, installation

I have a web project (DigiAppWeb) and a ejb project (DocuEJB) in eclipse. Both are maven modules of a POM project (DigiApp). I'm using maven integrated in eclipe. When I do a maven install of ejb proyect everything works fine. But when I do a maven install of web proyect it doesn't work.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project DigiAppWeb: Could not resolve dependencies for project    com.ieci.mugeju:DigiAppWeb:war:1.0: Failed to collect dependencies at com.ieci.mugeju:DocuEjb:jar:1.0: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.ieci.mugeju:DocuEjb:jar:1.0: Failure to find com.ieci.mugeju:DigiApp:pom:1.0 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project DigiAppWeb: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.ieci.mugeju:DigiAppWeb:war:1.0: Failed to collect dependencies at com.ieci.mugeju:DocuEjb:jar:1.0
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:220)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:127)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved(MojoExecutor.java:257)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:200)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:46)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionException: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.ieci.mugeju:DigiAppWeb:war:1.0: Failed to collect dependencies at com.ieci.mugeju:DocuEjb:jar:1.0
at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:167)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:195)
... 23 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.collection.DependencyCollectionException: Failed to collect dependencies at com.ieci.mugeju:DocuEjb:jar:1.0
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:292)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:317)
at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:159)
... 24 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.ieci.mugeju:DocuEjb:jar:1.0
at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:370)
at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:217)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:461)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:261)
... 26 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.model.resolution.UnresolvableModelException: Failure to find com.ieci.mugeju:DigiApp:pom:1.0 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultModelResolver.resolveModel(DefaultModelResolver.java:126)
at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParentExternally(DefaultModelBuilder.java:817)
at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParent(DefaultModelBuilder.java:669)
at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:307)
at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:361)
... 29 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to find com.ieci.mugeju:DigiApp:pom:1.0 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:459)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:262)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:239)
at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultModelResolver.resolveModel(DefaultModelResolver.java:122)
... 33 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Failure to find com.ieci.mugeju:DigiApp:pom:1.0 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:232)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:206)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.gatherDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:599)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:518)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:436)
... 36 more
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: it is a bit weird maven tries to resolve "com.ieci.mugeju:DigiApp:pom:1.0" from the maven central repository. It seems that is one of your artifacts? Maybe the install of that artifact did not work or it has a different version or the dependency on your project is wrong? Or you could try to delete the com/ieci/mugeju folder in your local repository. Sometimes maven caches attempts and will not retry immediately. There should be a marker file there - but deleting the folder will delete that file too.

Comment: DigiApp is one of my artifacts and it is the parent project. The version of all artifacts is 1.0, so the version is not the problem. I've tried to delete the com/ieci/mugeju folder in my local repository, but it doesn't work. What it seems a little bit strange for me is that DigiApp is the parent module, so why is looking it in the repository when I do a maven install on DigiWebApp?

Comment: @wemu Ok, I've solved my problem. The problem wasn't in DigiWebApp project, it was in DigiApp project. If I tried to install DigiApp I got an error about "java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersion". Changing the JDK version in DigiApp project resolved the problem, and now I can install also the DigiWebApp. Thanks for your help.

Comment: glad the issue is gone :)